# How to copy more than 1 cell consecutively in MS-Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Consider my Table 1

| Block | Phone |
| --- | --- |
| Ratia | 8295206877 |
| Ratia | 9728212234 |
| Ratia | 9812306598 |
| Ratia | 8295358100 |
| Jakhal | 9468046590 |
| Jakhal | 9813869743 |
| Jakhal | 9306010587 |
| Jakhal | 9812047669 |

Now for my Table 2 (Resultant table) should look like this

| Block | Phone |
| --- | --- |
| Ratia | 8295206877 |
| Ratia | 9728212234 |
| Ratia | 9812306598 |
| Jakhal | 9468046590 |
| Jakhal | 9813869743 |
| Jakhal | 9306010587 |
| Jakhal | 9812047669 |
| Ratia | 8295206877 |
| Ratia | 9728212234 |
| Ratia | 9812306598 |
| Ratia | 8295358100 |
| Ratia | 8295206877 |
| Ratia | 9728212234 |

Wherever there is "Ratia" present in the resultant table, the phone number is looked up in order.

In between, if there's another word like "Jakhal" comes, then its phone number is looked up in order.

In simple terms, the sequence of phone numbers is the same for each block.

Comment: MS Excel or google spreadsheet?

Comment: Mainly it is MS Excel.

Comment: I have the solution but it will take approx. 10 hours to post ... patience, please :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you just want to sort the table by Phone and then by Block?

Comment: I would encourage you, in the interest of avoiding confusion, to remove the tag "google-sheets" from this post. While Excel and Google Sheets share some similar functionality, they are very different from one another, all the more as complexity of formulas increases.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your problem right. This is my solution with formulas only using one auxiliary column.

```
 E2: "=IF(D1=D2;IF(E1+1>=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14;D2);0;E1+1);0)"
 F2: "=OFFSET($A$1;E2+MATCH(D2;$A$2:$A$14;);1)"
```

Column E determins, where you are in the current block. Depending on the length of the original block the counting wraps back to `0`, e.g. in E8.

Column F finds the first occurence of the Name in column `A` and gets the values by their offsets from there.

[image: Excelsheet screenshot]